# percentile_cont in bigrquery

Tags: sql, r, google-bigquery, tidyverse, dbplyr

I would like to get the 20th percentile of a column in big query using dplyr syntax in bigrquery, but I keep getting the following errors.  Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(bigrquery)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)
billing <- YOUR_BILLING_INFO

con <- dbConnect(
  bigrquery::bigquery(),
  project = "publicdata",
  dataset = "samples",
  billing = billing
)

natality <- tbl(con, "natality")

natality %>%
  filter(year %in% c(1969, 1970)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(percentile_20 = percentile_cont(weight_pounds, 0.2))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Analytic function PERCENTILE_CONT cannot be called without an OVER clause at [1:16] [invalidQuery]
```

However, it is not clear how to include an OVER clause here.  How can I get the 20th percentile with dplyr syntax?

Comment: since you are trying to write a query - could you post an example outside of dplyr? would be less complicated to look at and reproduce - try it on http://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery

Comment: It looks like windows functions are not supported when using dplyr. https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2290